# Find "edges" in 32 bits word bitpattern

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Im trying to find the most efficient algorithm to count "edges" in a bit-pattern. An edge meaning a change from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. I am sampling each bit every 250 us and shifting it into a 32 bit unsigned variable.

This is my algorithm so far

```
void CountEdges(void)
{
    uint_least32_t feedback_samples_copy = feedback_samples;
    signal_edges = 0;

    while (feedback_samples_copy > 0)
    {
        uint_least8_t flank_information = (feedback_samples_copy & 0x03);

        if (flank_information == 0x01 || flank_information == 0x02)
        {
            signal_edges++;
        }

        feedback_samples_copy >>= 1;
    }
}
```

It needs to be at least 2 or 3 times as fast.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to bitwise XOR them together to get a bit pattern representing the flipped bits. Then use one of the bit counting tricks on this page: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html to count how many 1's there are in the result.

Comment: Another link for this solution : http://tekpool.wordpress.com/category/bit-count/

Comment: I don't think it'll measure up against lookuptables though. For extreme memory constraint devices it might be the solution though. Although I would not expect someone to code C in that case but turn to assembly instead

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but how does XOR give "edges"? You can count the set bits, but the way I understand this, you need 00011101011 to be 5 (or 7 if you count the borders) and 1111100001111 to be 3.

Comment: he means by xoring the same value shifted by 1: edges = value ^ (value>>1)....  it then is a matter of counting the 1's in the edges variable

Answer (score 4):

One thing that may help is to precompute the edge count for all possible 8-bit value (a 512 entry lookup table, since you have to include the bit the precedes each value) and then sum up the count 1 byte at a time.

```
// prevBit is the last bit of the previous 32-bit word
// edgeLut is a 512 entry precomputed edge count table
// Some of the shifts and & are extraneous, but there for clarity
edgeCount = 
    edgeLut[(prevBit << 8) | (feedback_samples >> 24) & 0xFF] + 
    edgeLut[(feedback_samples >> 16) & 0x1FF] + 
    edgeLut[(feedback_samples >>  8) & 0x1FF] + 
    edgeLut[(feedback_samples >>  0) & 0x1FF];

prevBit = feedback_samples & 0x1;
```

Comment: why & with 0x1f?   you are ignoring 3 bits per byte this way

Comment: I comment faster than my shadow apparently  ;^)

Comment: (prevBit << 4)   should be (prevBit << 8)   ;^)

Comment: Shoot, this time you commented while I was editing :-P  Good to have another bit twiddler watching my back :-]

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

- copy your input value to a temp variable, left shifted by one
- copy the LSB of your input to yout temp variable
- XOR the two values. Every bit set in the result value represents one edge.
- use [this algorithm](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) to count the number of bits set.

This might be the code for the first 3 steps:

```
uint32 input; //some value
uint32 temp = (input << 1) | (input & 0x00000001);
uint32 result = input ^ temp;

//continue to count the bits set in result
//...
```

Comment: +1. I was about to write something similar. My first thought was `temp = (intput >> 1) ^ (input & 0x7FFFFFFFu); return countBits(temp);`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Create a look-up table so you can get the transitions within a byte or 16-bit value in one shot - then all you need to do is look at the differences in the 'edge' bits between bytes (or 16-bit values).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at only 2 bits during every iteration.
The fastest algorithm would probably be to build a hash table for all possibles values. Since there are 2^32 values that is not the best idea.
But why don't you look at 3, 4, 5 ... bits in one step? You can for instance precalculate for all 4 bit combinations your edgecount. Just take care of possible edges between the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

you could always use a lookup table for say 8 bits at a time
this way you get a speed improvement of around 8 times

don't forget to check for bits in between those 8 bits though. These then have to be checked 'manually'